# CiviContribute giving errors

Tags: error

Couple issue I wanted to gets some input on.  First, has anyone ever seen this error message: LESS error: .black is undefined: failed at `.black !important;` sites/all/themes/shriver/style.less on line 1091, sites/all/themes/shriver/style.less

I'm thinking a file is missing.

Second question: The monthly contribution check box is all the way in the top left corner of the page instead of next to the text.

Any fixes??????

Comment: Can you attach some screenshot? I feel the issue is probably with the theme.

Comment: It won't let me attached a screen shot here

Comment: Can you explain what prevents you uploading an image via the image icon?

Comment: Generally, it is preferred to post each question you have as a separate question in StackExchange. That way answers to your question can be voted up or down separately.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a theming issue that is not necessarily specific to civicrm. can you try a different theme. also update your Question to include your CMS.